# not able to (re-)mount or access files from a shared drive that I previously was able to access in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive, oserror

How can I fix this problem in Google Colaboratory? I can see the shared Google Drive in the left hand side pan and I was able to access it earlier after mounting (did so twice and both times worked) now I cannot even do a simple ls and even mounting doesn't work.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-88-d4ac8fae0180>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic('cd /')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in magic
    return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-84>", line 2, in cd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py", line 288, in cd
    oldcwd = py3compat.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 725, in getmodule
    file = getabsfile(object, _filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 709, in getabsfile
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(_filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 383, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's how I was trying to mount it which was previously working:

```
from google.colab import drive
from os.path import join
ROOT = "/content/drive"
print(ROOT)
drive.mount(ROOT, force_remount=True)
%cd "/content/drive/Shareddrives/Wish 2021"
```

And, here's the error I am getting:

```
/content/drive

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Mounted at /content/drive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-86-6e2ad087a71d>", line 6, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic('cd "/content/drive/Shareddrives/Wish 2021"')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in magic
    return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-84>", line 2, in cd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py", line 288, in cd
    oldcwd = py3compat.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 725, in getmodule
    file = getabsfile(object, _filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 709, in getabsfile
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(_filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 383, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am able to see wish 2021 in the left-hand side pane in Google Colab under `drive --> Shareddrives --> Wish 2021`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked after restarting the Google Colab notebook.

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/284#issuecomment-433505181

Thanks to jonno_FTW for the link.

> Runtime --> Restart and Run All

Comment: this is the temp solution. But I am facing this issue every 10 mins. I cannot restart the runtime every 5-10 mins

Comment: hi i have same problem and google colab shows many errors as following: 
 ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.                                                   OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected                      
 AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'           
  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()                                 
  AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'    please help me to fix above errors